# Create binary data iostream

Tags: c++, boost-asio, iostream

I am new to C++ and I am learning to use boost::asio for network programming to processing incoming binary data.  I come from embedded C where I would write packers and unpackers for the bits and byte received from the network socket using fixed buffer reads.

I want to learn about iostreams.  To read binary data from the network socket in boost::asio I am using streambuf.

Is it possible to develop an iostream that reads data types from the stream and consume them?

Is the correct approach to subclass from std::basic_streambuf?  Then consume the data from the stream using my data types.  I would not need to define fixed size buffers to perform reads.

I cannot quite get my head around how to do it.  Could some point to a suitable example of what I need to do.

I am doing this primarily as a learning experience to improve my C++ skills?

Thanks

Densha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't subclass `asio::streambuf`.

Instead, use either streamable types or e.g. Boost Serialization archives (`boost::archive::text_oarchive` and `boost::archive::text_iarchive`) or somesuch. This is quite highlevel and allows you serialize complete object graphs, including polymorphic types and (cyclic) relations.

Sadly, Boost Serialization doesn't afford a simple framing protocol so either your protocol should expect new connections for each message or add a framing protocol on top of it.

There are many samples. Start here, perhaps:

- [Examples of using cereal serialization and boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341936/examples-of-using-cereal-serialization-and-boostasio/47349404#47349404)
- [sending/receiving a struct in boost::asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236474/sending-receiving-a-struct-in-boostasio/47243908#47243908)
- Many many more https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bboost-asio%5D+serialization

PS. Be aware of other options

- much simpler POD approaches with `boost::asio::buffer` directly
- cereal, Cap'n-Proto, protobuf etc.

Comment: Sehe - Wow thanks for the answer.  I will read the examples and try to digest.  For my specific case I am reading data from a device that I don't own.  It has a binary protocol like.                                                                              <unit8 FC><unit8 length N><uint 8 1..N data>.  The variable length data is decoded differently depending on the function code (FC).  Which of these approaches would be best to investigate.

Comment: Huh. Why was that information not in the question? A lot of unfounded stuff about "subclassing" (?!) streambuf, but nothing about simple requirements that you... _did_ know? I suggest you edit the question, and then implement it in the simplest way - using any buffers (streambuf or (fixed) vector of uint8_t). Streams are really not related here, you  can use a stream on top off an array (`boost::iostreams::array_source` e.g.) just fine.